# Uploading animated GIF to Imgur API returns "Unable to determine file duration" error

Tags: http, curl, postman, imgur

I want to upload an animated GIF file to Imgur through their API but get an error message.

The file is converted from an mp4-file with GifTuna and is 15s duration, 30 FPS, ~70 MB.

I use the following command from the Windows 10 command line:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer [MYTOKEN]" -F "video=@myfile.gif" https://api.imgur.com/3/upload
```

Instead of an http status code 200, it returns the error message:

> {"status":400,"success":false,"data":{"error":"Unable to determine file duration","request":"/3/upload","method":"POST"}}

If I upload the original mp4-version, the upload is successful. If I try to upload the animated GIF through Imgurs own postman.com collection I get the same error message as with curl.

It doesn't seem to be a file size issue as the limit for videos is 200MB. Also, trying with a bigger file, say 300 MB, triggers a specific error stating the file is too big.

Any idea how to solve this?